# Heat transfer problem

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, energy, energy-conservation

I have a pipe with laminar flow and inlet temperature T1. Far away from the inlet (in the z direction) I have postulated the temperature (T) as a function of r and z (cylindrical coordinates). The walls of the pipe are adiabatic and i need to find the constant C. I know A & B
$$
T=A*z+B*r+C
 $$
I have already used Fourier's law at the wall to get another constant=0 how do i perform an energy balance to find the remaining C knowing the pipe wall is adiabatic.

Comment: Please provide some more context.  As presented, this really can't be answered intelligently.

Comment: Measure T  as a function of r and z and fit the curve with C variable to get the C that fits.